# Getting Data in Single Column using comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a table with below data

```
column1   column2

DIU02   3D ITEM MAINTENANCE
DIU02   DISTRIBUTION ITEM UPDATE APPLICATION
DIU02   DIU - Distribution Item Update
```

I want for unique DIU02 , all data come in single column using comma seperation.

Its for SQL Server Database

```
DIU02   3D ITEM MAINTENANCE,DISTRIBUTION ITEM UPDATE APPLICATION,DIU - Distribution Item Update
```

Comment: in `mysql`, `sql`, `sql-server` or `oracle` or all **4**?

Comment: For SQL Server GGio..

Answer (score 0):

try this in MySQL:

```
SELECT column1, GROUP_CONCAT(column2)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY column1
```

If you want specifically for only `DIU02` cell just do this:

```
SELECT column1, GROUP_CONCAT(column2)
FROM MyTable
WHERE column1 = 'DIU02'
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can archive by this way

```
DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Data = COALESCE(@Data + ',', '') + column2
FROM Table
WHERE column1= 'DIU02'
```